# Is this the the correct way for constructing Coproduct in $\textbf{Vect}$?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, coproduct

The following question is taken from "Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative" and "Algebraic Approaches to Program Semantics" both by: Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ [From "Arrows, structures, and functors"]

$\textbf{Proposition:}$  Given a family $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ of vector spaces, we define their $\textbf{weak direct sum}$ to be

$$\coprod_{i\in I}A_i=\{f\mid f:I\to \cup_{i \in I}A_i;f(i)\in A_i \text{ 
for each }i;\text{ and supp}(f)\text{ is finite}\}$$

considered as a subspace of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i.$  Then $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i$ together with the injections

$\text{in}_j:A_j\rightarrow$  $\coprod_{i\in I} A_i:$$a_j\mapsto$ the $f$ with $f(i)=0$ for $i\neq j,$ and with $f(j)=a_j$ is a coproduct of $(A_i)$ in the category $\textbf{Vect}.$

$\textbf{(2)}$ There is also an exercise question similar to the above proposition in the text "Algebraic Approaches to Program Semantics" by the same two authors, and the exercise alongg with the relevant definition are included in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I would like to know if the following is a correct concrete description of the coproduct for category of vector spaces in $\textbf{Proposition:}$ above.

$\textbf{Coproduct}$

For $i=1,2$ and $I=\{1,2\}$ let $f:\{1,2\}\to A_1\sqcup A_2:i\mapsto f(i),$ and

For the injection map $\text{in}_j:A_j\mapsto A_1\sqcup A_2:a_j\mapsto f(i)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $f(j)=a_j$ for $i=j,$ with $f$ being a linear map.  With 'coordinatewise' addition and multiplication by a-scalar, then $f$ being linear means if $f'\in A_1\sqcup A_2,$ then $(f+f')(i)=f(i)+f'(i)$ and $(\lambda\cdot f)(i)=\lambda\cdot f(i).$  So $f+f'\in A_1\sqcup A_2$ $\lambda\cdot f\in A_1\sqcup A_2$

For the unique map $q$ that completes the commutative triangle in the theorem, $q:A_1\sqcup A_2\to C:f\mapsto q_1(f(1))+q_2(f(2)),$ $q(f)(1)=q_1(f(1))+q_2(0)=q_1(a_1)+q_2(0),$ and $q(f)(2)=q_1(0)+q_2(f(2))=q_1(0)+q_2(a_2)$

Linearity of $\text{in}_j$ and $q$ maps,

Injection map:

Let $a'_1\in A_1,a'_2\in A_2,$ and $f,f'\in A_1\sqcup A_2,$

$\text{in}_j:A_j\mapsto A_1\sqcup A_2:a_j\mapsto (f+f')(i)=0$ for $i\neq j,$ and $(f+f')(j)=a_1+a'_1$ for $i=j,$

$\text{in}_j:A_j\mapsto A_1\sqcup A_2:a_j\mapsto (\lambda\cdot f)(i)=0$ for $i\neq j,$ and $\lambda\cdot f(j)=\lambda\cdot a_j$ for $i=j,$

$q$ map:

Let $a'_1\in A_1,a'_2\in A_2,$ and $f,f'\in A_1\sqcup A_2,$ then

$q:A_1\sqcup A_2\to C:f+f'\mapsto q_1((f+f')(1))+q_2((f+f')(2)),$ $q(f+f')(1)=q_1((f+f')(1))+q_2(0)=q_1(a_1+a'_1)+q_2(0),$ and

$q((f+f'))(2)=q_1(0)+q_2((f+f')(2))=q_1(0)+q_2(a_2+a'_2)$

$q:A_1\sqcup A_2\to C:\lambda\cdot f\mapsto q_1((\lambda\cdot f)(1))+q_2((\lambda\cdot f)(2)),$ $q((\lambda\cdot f))(1)=q_1((\lambda\cdot f)(1))+q_2(0)=q_1(\lambda\cdot a_1)+q_2(0),$ and $q((\lambda\cdot f))(2)=q_1(0)+q_2((\lambda\cdot f)(2))=q_1(0)+q_2(\lambda\cdot a_2)$

I am not sure why I am getting $q_1(0), q_2(0)$ terms and what they are suppose to be equal to in the above four cases: $(f+f')(1), (f+f')(2), (\lambda\cdot f)(1), (\lambda\cdot f)(2)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They're already given a concrete description? I'm not sure what you're looking for. FYI if $I$ is finite then the coproduct $\cong$ the product for vector spaces

Comment: Your $q$ looks correct. If $q_1:A_1\to X$ and $q_2:A_2\to X$ are linear maps then $f\mapsto q_1(f(1))+q_2(f(2)):A_1\sqcup A_2\to X$ is linear and the unique lift of $q_1,q_2$ along $\mathrm{in}_1,\,\mathrm{in}_2$

Comment: @FShrike I just want to see if I am understanding correctly with concrete examples for $I=\{1,2,\}$ and am I understanding the $q$ map correctly?  Specifically are these $q(f+f')(1)=q_1((f+f')(1))+q_2(0)=q_1(a_1+a'_1)+q_2(0),$ and $q((f+f'))(2)=q_1(0)+q_2((f+f')(2))=q_1(0)+q_2(a_2+a'_2)$ correct.

Comment: @FShrike I attached a screenshots of an exercise with the relevant definition from another text by the same two authors.  In hint of exercise 5i) where it says $\langle f_1,f_2\rangle(x_1,x_2)=f_1(x_2)+f_2(x_2),$ the notation $\langle f_1,f_2\rangle$ corresponds to the $q_i$ for $i=1,2$. in $\textbf{Proposition}$ in $\textbf{(1)}.$  But for some reasons, in my construction, I am getting $q_1(0)$ and $q_2(0)$ terms.

Comment: @FShrike can I ask you to take a look at the following about [automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731690/how-to-fill-out-the-last-row-for-the-included-sequential-machine-table).  I am having trouble making out heads and tails over notations.  Also, I posted about  [coproduct for monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733556/constructing-coproduct-in-category-of-monoid-and-possible-misprint).  Basically, I just want to see if there is a misprint, and if I am understanding the word reduction rules correctly.  I also gave a specific example.

Comment: @FShrike I also posted about [binary coproduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733558/binary-coproduct-for-abelian-monoid-and-monoid) and it is about how to read the modified exercise correctly, in relations to this current exercise and also  [coproduct for monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733556/constructing-coproduct-in-category-of-monoid-and-possible-misprint) .  I think the coproduct for both are different.  Would it need to be proved, if so, how.