# Correct way for coproduct construction in $\textbf{Abm},$ the category of Abelian monoid?

Tags: category-theory, monoid, coproduct

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ $\textbf{Definition 1:}$ A $\textbf{monoid}$ is a set $X$ equipped with a function $\cdot:X\times X\to X$ (with monoid $\textbf{multiplication}$) and a distinguished element (the monoid $\textbf{identity}$) subject to the two laws:

$x\cdot (y\cdot z)=(x \cdot y)\cdot z$ for all $x,y,z$

$x\cdot e=x=e\cdot x$  for all $x.$

We abbreviate $x\cdot y$ to $xy.$

$\textbf{(2)}$ $\textbf{Definition 2:}$ If $X,Y$ are monoids, a function $f:X\to Y$ is a monoid $\textbf{homomorphism}$ if $f$ preserves the monoid structure of multiplication and identities, i.e., if $f(x\cdot x')=f(x)\cdot f(x')$ and $f(e)=e.$

The $\textbf{identity function}$ $\text{id}_X:X\to X$ is surely a monoid homomorphism and the usual $\textbf{composite}$ $g\cdot f: X\to X$ of two functions is a monoid homomorphism if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z.$

$\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{Proposition 3:}$  Given a family $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ of vector spaces, we define their $\textbf{weak direct sum}$ to be

$$\coprod_{i\in I}A_i=\{f\mid f:I\to \cup_{i \in I}A_i;f(i)\in A_i \text{ 
for each }i;\text{ and supp}(f)\text{ is finite}\}$$

considered as a subspace of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i.$  Then $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i$ together with the injection maps

$\text{in}_j:A_j\to \coprod_{i\in I}A_i:a_j\mapsto$ the $f$ with $f(i)=0$  for $i\neq j,$ and with $f(j)=a_j$

is a coproduct of $(A_i)$ in the category $\textbf{Vect}.$

$\textbf{(4)}$ $\textbf{Assumed exercise:}$

A monoid $X$ is $\textbf{abelian}$ if $xy=yx$ for all $x,y.$  Let $\textbf{Abm}$ be the category of abelian monoids and monoid homomorphisms.  Prove that products, equalizers and coequalizers can be constructed by mimicking these constructs in $\textbf{Mon}$ or $\textbf{Grp}.$  Construct coproducts in $\textbf{Abm}$ by imitating the construction in $\textbf{Vect}$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

Constructing the coproduct of $\textbf{Abm},$ by modifying notations as necessary in $\textbf{Proposition 3:}$ above in $\textbf{(3)},$ in a concrete example:

Let $I=\{1,2\},$  Let $A_1=X_1$ and $A_2=X_2,$ and $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2\in X_2,$ a monoid homomorphic map $f(x_1\cdot x_2)=f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2),$ with the assumption that $x_1\cdot x_2=x_2\cdot x_1.$ So $f\in \coprod_{i\in I}X_i.$ means for $I=\{1,2\},$ $f\in X_1\sqcup X_2,$ we have $f:\{1,2\}\to X_1\sqcup X_2:f\mapsto f(i),$ and $f(x_1\cdot x_2):\{1,2\}\to X_1\sqcup X_2:f(x_1\cdot x_2)\mapsto f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2).$

For the injection maps which are also monoid homomorphism, $\text{in}_j:X_j\mapsto X_1\sqcup X_2:x_j\mapsto f(x_i)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $f(x_j)=x_j$ for $i=j,$ with $f$ being a monoid homomorphic map. $\text{in}_j(x_1\cdot x_2)=f(x_1\cdot x_2)=f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2)=\text{in}_j(x_1)\cdot \text{in}_j(x_2)$ and hence $\text{in}_1(x_1\cdot x_2)=f(x_1\cdot x_2)=x_1,$ $\text{in}_2(x_1\cdot x_2)=f(x_1\cdot x_2)=x_2$

For the $q$ homomorphic map being defined as: $q:\coprod_{i\in I}X_i\to C:f\mapsto \cdot_{i\in I}q_i(\text{in}_j(x_j))=\cdot_{i\in I}q_i(f(x_i))=q_i(0)$ for $i\neq j$ and $\cdot_{i\in I}q_i(\text{in}_j(x_j))=\cdot_{i\in I}q_i(f(x_i))=q_i(x_i)$ for $i=j,$

and so,

$q:\coprod_{i\in I}X_i\to C:f\mapsto \cdot_{i\in I=\{1,2\}}q_i(\text{in}_j(x_1\cdot x_2))= \cdot_{i\in I}q_i(f(x_1\cdot x_2))=q_i(f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2))=q_i(f(x_1))\cdot q_i(f(x_2)),$

With $I=\{1,2\},$ $i=1,2,$ $j=1,2,$ $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2\in X_2,$ gives

$q:X_1\sqcup X_2\to C:f\mapsto q_1(\text{in}_1(x_1\cdot x_2)=q_1(f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2))=q_1(f(x_1))\cdot q_1(f(x_2))=q_1(x_1)\cdot q_1(0),$

$q:X_1\sqcup X_2\to C:f\mapsto q_1(\text{in}_2(x_1\cdot x_2)=q_1(f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2))=q_1(f(x_1))\cdot q_1(f(x_2))=q_1(0)\cdot q_1(x_2),$

$q:X_1\sqcup X_2\to C:f\mapsto q_2(\text{in}_1(x_1\cdot x_2)=q_2(f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2))=q_2(f(x_1))\cdot q_2(f(x_2))=q_2(x_1)\cdot q_2(0),$

$q:X_1\sqcup X_2\to C:f\mapsto q_2(\text{in}_2(x_1\cdot x_2)=q_2(f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2))=q_2(f(x_1))\cdot q_2(f(x_2))=q_2(0)\cdot q_2(x_2),$

I am not sure why I am getting $q_1(0), q_2(0)$ terms and what they are suppose to be equal to in the above four cases.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I might suggest you also google how to make the coproduct from trustworthy sources, and then compare. As it stands this is just a lot of notation to read, it'd be a better question if it was focused e.g. you saw something in the "official" construction that you didn't understand or didn't use in your construction

Comment: @FShrike actually, I have something else to ask you later if that is okay.  One is similar to this.  The other ones have to do with some old post that I said I was going to get back to you. I tried looking up for this and the one I am about to post in a bit.  I could not find the answer.  Also, I think it might be good to go through the formalism at least once.  I am writing out all the details as if this is an assignment.

Comment: @FShrike ..I spoke with grad students who have taken homological algebra where they learned a bit of category theory, they did not do exercises on every single concept, also, they told me the course simply did not have time.

Comment: Some people swear by exercises. I do them more often now especially self-set once but for a long time I never did. Leinster’s book is the only book where I actually did and enjoyed doing basically every exercise

Comment: @FShrike, there is a reason I asked you about this exercise, the ones about coproduct in the category of Vector spaces, and another one that I will  post shortly.  Because all three exercises have to do with another exercise which I don't understand, but I need to know how to do these three first.  I think Leinster's text is good if you are well versed in undergrad math.  Arbib and Manes is in between Leinster and Colin McLarty's text.  I don't know if you have seen Arbib and Manes' text, I am wondering whether I should learn the chapters on cartesian closed category and universal algebra.

Comment: @FShrike I am doing the exercises because one can fool oneself about thinking that they understand something, but when asked about the details, they are having difficulty in answering.

Comment: yeah don't get me wrong, exercises are important. Bear in mind one should strike a balance because it's good, motivation wise, to move on a little bit and learn some new content. Learning new content can help you to revise the old stuff do and do the exercises you were previously stuck on. My own exercise solving ability has increased significantly over the last year

Comment: The point of the exercise is simply to convince yourself that the definition for monoids is word for word the same as that for vector spaces. You do seem to have a confusion about the function $f:I\to A_i$ being some kind of monoid homomorphism. But it’s just a set function. There are also various confusions where you write $f\in X_1\sqcup X_2, f:I\to X_1\sqcup X_2, f(i):I\to X_1\sqcup X_2,$ three expressions that are all inconsistent with each other.

Comment: @FShrike  I think the inconsistency in notation stems from $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i=\{f\mid f:I\to \cup_{i \in I}A_i;f(i)\in A_i \text{ 
for each }i;\text{ and supp}(f)\text{ is finite}\}$.  If we have $f:I\to \cup_{i \in I}A_i,$ $f(i)\in A_i \text{ 
for each }i;\text{ and supp}(f)\text{ is finite},$ then $f\in \coprod_{i\in I}A_i?$  Did I got the $q$ map correct?  I try to get where the elements get mapped to be correct for $f$ and $\{in}_j$ maps.

Comment: (really that should have been @ Kevin Arlin) - this really is the same as the vector one. Replace all instances of "$+$" in the vector definition with $\cdot$ (the monoid action) and you're good (and forget about the scalar multiplication)

Comment: This is a mess of notation. If you want your $q_i$ to be homomorphisms it should follow $q_i(0)=0$

Comment: @FShrike similar to the post [$\textbf{Vect}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732499/is-this-the-the-correct-way-for-constructing-coproduct-in-textbfvect) why am I getting the $_1(0)$
 and $_2(0)$
 terms? I am not sure what they are suppose to be equal to.  (I reposted my comment for clarification, since the latex code was messed up.)

Comment: @FShrike so same for the other post: [$\textbf{Vect}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732499/is-this-the-the-correct-way-for-constructing-coproduct-in-textbfvect) why am I getting the $_1(0)$
 and $_2(0)$, the $q_i(0)=0.$  Is that correct?  But for my other post for vector space, I am getting four cases for the $q-$ maps.

Comment: In all cases $q_i(0)=0$ must be true (otherwise your map fails to be linear / a homomorphism)

Comment: Also I am currently away, I can’t respond to all comments just yet. That’s why my activity has been on-and-off