# Binary coproduct for abelian monoid and monoid.

Tags: category-theory, monoid, coproduct

The following is taken from the text $\textit{Algebraic approaches to program semantics}$ by:  Arbib and Manes, and "Categories for Types" by Roy L.Crole.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{From}$ Crole's "Categories for Types".

$\textbf{Definition 1:} A$ $\textit{binary coproduct}$ of objects $A$ and $B$ in a category $C$ is specified by

an object $A+B$ of $C,$ together with

two $\textit{insertion}$ morphism $i_A:A\to A+B$ and $i_B:B\to A+B,$ such that for each morphisms $f:A\to C,g:B\to C$ there exists a unique morphism $[f,g]:A+B\to C$ for which $[f,g]\circ i_A:=f$ and $[f,g]\circ i_B:=g.$

We can extend this definition to the notion of a coproduct of a set indexed family of objects.  Given a family of objects $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ in a category $C,$ where $I$ is a set, a $\textit{coproducts}$ is specified by the following data.

An object $\sum_{i\in I}A_i$ in $C,$ and |

For every $j\in I,$ a morphism $i_j:A_j\to \sum_{i\in I}A_i$ called the $j-\textit{th coproduct insertion,}$

such that for any object $C$ and any family morphisms $(f_i:A_i\to C\mid i\in I)$ there is a unique morphism $[f_i\mid i\in I]:\sum_{i\in I}A_i\to C$ for which gien any $j\in I,$we have $[f_i\mid i\in I]\circ i_j=f_j.$

$\textbf{From}$ Arbib and Manes' "Categorical Imperative...".

$\textbf{Definition 2:}$ $\textit{Coproducts in}$ $\textbf{Mon} \textit{ or}$ $\textbf{Grp}$

The one element monoid/group $\{e\}$ is clearly initial object-that is, the empty coproduct-in both categories.

Let now $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ be a family of monoids with $I$ non-empty.  Let $A$ for 'alphabet') be the disjoint union of the sets $X_i.$  Let $W$ be the set $A*$ of all words on the alphabet $A.$  A word $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is $\textit{reduced}$ if for all $j<n, i_i\neq i_{j+1}$ and for all $j\leq, x_j\neq e_j$ (where $a_j=(x_j,i_j)$ and $e_j$ is the unit of $X_{i_j}).$  If a word is not reduced it has a $\textit{reduction}$ obtained by continuing to apply the following rules:

(a)  Multiply adjacent pairs with the same $i-$term:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_j=(x_j,i),a_{j+1}=(x_{j+1},i),\ldots,a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_j=(x_jx_{j+1},i),a_{j+2},\ldots,a_n)$

(b)  Delete identity terms:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_j=(e_j,i_j),\ldots a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n)$

$\textbf{Assumed exercise 1:}$

A monoid $X$ is $\textbf{abelian}$ if $xy=yx$ for all $x,y.$  Let $\textbf{Abm}$ be the category of abelian monoids and monoid homomorphisms.  Prove that products, equalizers and coequalizers can be constructed by mimicking these constructs in $\textbf{Mon}$ or $\textbf{Grp}.$  Construct coproducts in $\textbf{Abm}$ by imitating the construction in $\textbf{Vect}$

$\textbf{Assumed exercise 2:}$

Verify that a product of semilattices, as constructed in $\textbf{Abm}$, is still a semilatticve.  State and prove a similar statement for equalizers, coequalizers and coproducts.

$\color{Blue}{Exercise:}$

Show that, replacing (abelian monoids, semilattices) with (monoids, abelian monoids), $\textbf{assumed exercise 2}$ goes through for products, equalizers and coequalizers but not for binary coproducts.

$\color{red}{Questions:}$

In the $\color{Blue}{Exercise},$ above, is the replace version reads as: "Verify that a product of abelian monoids, as constructed in monoids, is still a monoid.  Also, for binary coproducts given in $\textbf{Definition 1:},$ the exercise won't go through because they are not the same.  I posted about coproduct for [abelian monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732906/correct-way-for-coproduct-construction-in-textbfabm-the-category-of-abelia?noredirect=1#comment10033547_4732906) and [monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733556/constructing-coproduct-in-category-of-monoid-and-possible-misprint).  If they are indeed consider different, how can that be proven?  Perhaps, that the two are not isomorphic.  But I am not sure how to set it up mathematically speaking and how to prove it afterwards.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Let’s keep our heads screwed on. In this post you give a construction for the coproduct of monoids and you write the statement: “show coproducts of Abelian monoids can be made by imitating the construction in Vect”. You just need to assess whether or not the two constructions are the same.

Comment: @FShrike I don't have to show that the two coproducts (abelian monoids, monoids) are not isomorphic?  Also, is "Verify that a product of abelian monoids, as constructed in monoids, is still a monoid" the correct rephrasing.  The way the exercise ask the reader to replace the categories, I am not sure if i am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be confusion about what the exercise is actually asking of you.

A product of (Abelian) monoids in the category of monoids is obviously a monoid, given you already know that the category of monoids has products. The correct and clearer exercise statement should be: “show that a coproduct of Abelian monoids *in the category of monoids* is not necessarily Abelian” (but show that the product, equaliser etc. of Abelian monoids in the category of monoids *is* Abelian).

This is pointing out that one constructs the coproduct of Abelian monoids by imitating the construction for vector spaces, **not** by imitating the construction for (general) monoids *since that doesn’t work* in the category of Abelian monoids. This is also observing that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{AbMon}\to\mathsf{Mon}$ is not cocontinuous (which allows us to infer it has no right adjoint i.e. no ‘cofree’ construction exists).

Comment: when you say "show that a coproduct of Abelian monoids in the category of monoids is not necessarily Abelian",  do you mean i construct the coproduct of abelian monoid  the way I construct coproduct for vector s;paces, and the resulting coproduct, I construct the coproduct in the form of regular monoid, and then show that it is not abelian?

Comment: @Seth That’s a bit unclear but sounds like you want to compute the coproduct of the coproduct, which doesn’t really make sense. Just skip to the last thing you said: “I construct the coproduct in the form of regular monoid, and then show that it is not [in general] Abelian?” - that’s right.

Comment: in your rephrasing, "show that a coproduct of Abelian monoids in the category of monoids is not necessarily Abelian" I don't understand what it means by after constructing the coproduct of an abelian monoid, what does it mean to be "in the category of monoids is not necessarily abelian"

Comment: I mentioned to you about struggling to understand this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731690/how-to-fill-out-the-last-row-for-the-included-sequential-machine-table), should I redo the post.  I am not sure why no one is commenting since I am dealing with issues of notational difficulties.

Comment: @Seth you’ve tripped up on the language again. Let $J$ be some set, $(A_j)_{j\in J}$ a family of Abelian monoids. There is a *coproduct of monoids*, using the construction with reduced words etc., $M=\bigsqcup_{j\in J}A_j$. The question is: *is $M$ Abelian?* The answer should be “no, not in general”.

Comment: As for the other post, it’s not too uncommon for questions on MSE to receive no attention for a while. That’s happened to a few of mine before. I personally don’t find the question very interesting, frankly, (regardless of whether or not it is easy) and I guess that’s what most other readers have felt. It also isn’t very category-theoretic tbh; feel completely free to move on from that exercise and maybe return to it later

Comment: it was an example of how category theory is applied in computer science.  It is also used later on to concretely illustrate what a is a concrete functor.  One of the author of the textbook is a computer scientists.  He just writes badly.  His co-author who is a mathematician did not do enough hand holding.