# Correct Construction of coproduct in category of monoid, and possible misprint?

Tags: category-theory, monoid, coproduct

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ $\textbf{(Definition 1)}$ A $\textbf{monoid}$ is a set $X$ equipped with a function $\cdot:X\times X\to X$ (with monoid $\textbf{multiplication}$) and a distinguished element (the monoid $\textbf{identity}$) subject to the two laws:

$x\cdot (y\cdot z)=(x \cdot y)\cdot z$ for all $x,y,z$

$x\cdot e=x=e\cdot x$  for all $x.$

We abbreviate $x\cdot y$ to $xy.$

$\textbf{(1)}$ $\textbf{Definition 1:}$ If $X,Y$ are monoids, a function $f:X\to Y$ is a monoid $\textbf{homomorphism}$ if $f$ preserves the monoid structure of multiplication and identities, i.e., if $f(x\cdot x')=f(x)\cdot f(x')$ and $f(e)=e.$

The $\textbf{identity function}$ $\text{id}_X:X\to X$ is surely a monoid homomorphism and the usual $\textbf{composite}$ $g\cdot f: X\to X$ of two functions is a monoid homomorphism if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z.$

$\textbf{(2)}$ $\textbf{Example:}$ from the $\textit{theory of computation:}$

Consider a set $A$ (the 'alphabet') and let $X$ be the set of all $\textit{word on the alphabet A,}$ i.e., $X$ is the set of all strings $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ with each $a_i\in A.$  We do not exclude the case $n=0;$ there is one such string, call it $\wedge,$ the 'empty string'.  Define $(a_1\ldots a_n)\cdot (b_1\ldots b_m)=(a_1\ldots a_n, b_1\ldots b_m)$ and define $e=\wedge.$  With this structure, $X$ becomes a monoid.  $X$ is denoted by $A^{*},$ and is called $\textbf{free monoid on the set}$ $A$ $\textbf{of generators.}$

$\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{Definition 3:}$ $\textit{Coproducts in}$ $\textbf{Mon}$ or $\textbf{Grp}$

The one element monoid/group $\{e\}$ is clearly initial object-that is, the empty coproduct-in both categories.

Let now $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ be a family of monoids with $I$ non-empty.  Let $A$ (for 'alphabet') be the disjoint union of the sets $X_i.$  Let $W$ be the set $A*$ of all words on the alphabet $A.$  A word $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is $\textit{reduced}$ if for all $j<n, i_j\neq i_{j+1}$ and for all $j\leq, x_j\neq e_j$ (where $a_j=(x_j,i_j)$ and $e_j$ is the unit of $X_{i_j}).$  If a word is not reduced it has a $\textit{reduction}$ obtained by continuing to apply the following rules:

$\textbf{(a)}$  Multiply adjacent pairs with the same $i-$term:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_j=(x_j,i),a_{j+1}=(x_{j+1},i),\ldots,a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_j=(x_jx_{j+1},i),a_{j+2},\ldots,a_n)$

$\textbf{(b)}$   Delete identity terms:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_j=(e_j,i_j),\ldots a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n)$

until the word is reduced.  It is obvious that such a process has a most $n$ steps and results in a reduced word.  The monoid axioms guarantee that the end result is independent of the way the rules are applied (why?).  Let $C$ be the set of all reduced words in $W.$  Define a multiplication on $C$ by

$$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)(b_1,\ldots,b_m)=\text{reduction of }(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m).$$

Then $C$ is a monoid with unit $\wedge.$  Define injection homomorphisms

$$\text{in}_i:X_i\to C \quad x_i\mapsto\text{reduction of }(x_i,i)$$

These $\textit{are}$ monoid homomorphism by the reduction rules.  To check that $(\text{in}_i:X_i\to C\mid i\in I)$ is indeed a coproduct for the monoids $X_i$ we must check that whenever $f_i:X_i\to D$ are monoid homomorphisms, the diagram

[image]

commutes for a unique monoid homomorphism $f.$  But for $f$ to be a homomorphism it clearly must satisfy $f(\wedge)=e,$ while, for $n>0, f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=f_{i_1}(x_1)\ldots f_{i_n}(x_n)$ where $a_j=(x_j,i_j).$  But this determines $f$ as a function.  The proof that this $f$ is a monoid homomorphism is left as a routine exercise.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I have some questions about how one goes about constructing the coproduct for monoid, specifically my questions have to do with:

$\color{blue}{1)}$ elements in the disjoint union of sets,

$\color{blue}{2)}$ how the word reduction rule works in particular instance,

$\color{blue}{3)}$  Misprint in the definition of injection homomorphism

$\color{blue}{4)}$ what the maps $\text{in}_i, f_i$ and $f$ look like for particular values of $i$ and $j$

For $\color{blue}{1)}$ In the beginning second paragraph of $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{Definition 3:}$ where it says:

"Let now $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ be a family of monoids with $I$ non-empty.  Let $A$ (for 'alphabet') be the disjoint union of the sets $X_i.$"

There is the multiplication rule after applying word reduction:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)(b_1,\ldots,b_m)=\text{reduction of }(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m).$

Does that mean: $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in X_1$ and $(b_1,\ldots,b_m)\in X_2,$ $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)(b_1,\ldots,b_m)\in X_1\sqcup X_2,$ and $\text{reduction of }(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m)\in C?$

For $\color{blue}{2)}$ with the rules for word reduction, with as an example, $I=\{1,2\},$ $i=1,$ $n=10$, and $j=5,$ for $\textbf{(3)}$$\textbf{(a)}$

$(a_1,\ldots,a_5=(x_5,1),a_6=(x_6,1),\ldots,a_{10})\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_5=(x_5x_6,1),a_7,\ldots,a_{10})$

with $i=1,2,$ $n=10,$ and $j=8.$ for $\textbf{(3)}$$\textbf{(b)}$

$(a_1,\ldots,a_8=(e_8,1_8),\ldots a_{10})\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_7,a_9,\ldots,a_{10})$

for $\color{blue}{3)}$  In $\textbf{(3)},$ Where the injection homomorphisms is defined:

"$\text{in}_i:X_i\to C \quad x_i\mapsto\text{reduction of }(x_i,i)$"

$\color{purple}{I}$ $\color{purple}{think}$ $\color{purple}{there}$ $\color{purple}{might}$ $\color{purple}{be}$ $\color{purple}{a}$ $\color{purple}{misprint.}$ I think it should be

$$\text{in}_i:X_i\to C \quad x_j\mapsto\text{reduction of }(x_j,i_j),$$

because the $i$ in $\text{in}_i, (x_j,i_j)$ refers to which $X_i$ the $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ belongs to, and for the $j$s in $x_j, a_j=(x_j,i_j)$ refers to the specific $a_j, a_j=x_j-$th terms where $1\leq j \leq n.$

For $\color{blue}{4)}$ as a specific example with $i=1,2,$ $n,m=10,$ and as above for $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{(a)}$ $j=5,$ for multiplying adjacent terms and $\textbf{(3)}$$\textbf{(b)}$ $j=8$ for deletion of terms:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_{10})(b_1,\ldots, b_{10})\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_5=(x_5x_6,1),a_7,a_9,a_{10})(b_1,\ldots,\hat{b}_5=(x_5x_6,1),b_7,b_9,b_{10})=(a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_5,a_7,a_9,a_{10},b_1,\ldots,\hat{b}_5,b_7,b_9,b_{10})$

For the injection maps, which is also a homomorphism.

$\text{in}_i:X_i\to C,$ $C=X_1\sqcup X_2,$

for $i=1,j=5$ for $\textbf{(3)},$ $\textbf{(a)},$ $\text{in}_1:X_1\to X_1\sqcup X_2:\text{in}_1(a_1,\ldots, a_{10})=(a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_5,a_7,a_9,a_{10})=((x_1,1_1),\ldots,(x_5,1_5),(x_7,1_7),(x_9,1_9),(x_{10},1_{10})),$  $a_j,(x_j,1_j)$ are both elements of $X_1$

and for

$i=2,$ for $x'_j\in X_2,$ $j=8$ for $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{(b)},$  $\text{in}_2:X_2\to X_1\sqcup X_2:\text{in}_2(b_1,\ldots, b_{10})=(b_1,\ldots,\hat{b}_5,b_7,b_9,b_{10})=((x'_1,2_1),\ldots,(x'_5,2_5),(x'_7,2_7),(x'_9,2_9),(x'_{10},2_{10})),$ $b_j,(x'_j,2_j)$ are both elements of $X_2$

Then the homomorphic maps $f,$ $f\circ \text{in}_i=f_{i_j}$ defined in terms of elements are as follows:

with $i\in I,$ $f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=f(a_1)f(a_2)\cdots f(a_n)=f_{i_1}(x_1)f_{i_2}(x_2)\cdots f_{i_n}(x_n)$

and for $I=\{1,2\},$

$f((a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m))=(f(a_1)f(a_2)\cdots f(a_n), f(b_1)f(b_2)\cdots f(b_m))=(f_{1_1}(a_1)f_{1_2}(a_2)\cdots f_{1_n}(a_n), f_{2_1}(b_1)f_{2_2}(b_2)\cdots f_{2_m}(b_m))$

and for $i=1,n=10,j=5$ for $\textbf{(3)},$ $\textbf{(a)},$ and $j=8$ for $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{(b)},$

$(f\circ \text{in}_1)(a_1,\ldots, a_{10})=f(\text{in}_1(a_1,\ldots, a_{10}))=f_{1_1}(a_1)\ldots f_{1_5}(\hat{a}_5)f_{1_7}(a_7)f_{1_9}(a_9)f_{1_{10}}(a_{10})$

but, and so,

$(a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_5,a_7,a_9,a_{10})=((x_1,1_1),\ldots,(x_5,1_5),(x_7,1_7),(x_9,1_9),(x_{10},1_{10})),$ $a_j=(x_j,i_j),$

$f(a_1)\ldots f(\hat{a}_5)f(a_7)f(a_9)f(a_{10})=f(a_1)\ldots f(\hat{a}_5)f(a_7)f(a_9)f(a_{10})=f_{1_1}(x_1)\ldots f_{1_5}(\hat{x}_5)f_{1_7}(x_7)f_{1_9}(x_9)f_{1_{10}}(x_{10}))$

Finally, for $I=\{1,2\},n,m=10,$ $j=5$ for $\textbf{(3)},$ $\textbf{(a)},$ and $j=8$ for $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{(b)},$  we finally have:

$(f\circ \text{in}_i)((a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{10})(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_{10}))=(f\circ \text{in}_1(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{10})f\circ \text{in}_2(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_{10}))=(f(a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_5,a_7,a_9,a_{10}),f(b_1,\ldots,\hat{b}_5,b_7,b_9,b_{10})=(f_{1_1}(x_1)\ldots f_{1_5}(\hat{x}_5)f_{1_7}(x_7)f_{1_9}(x_9)f_{1_{10}}(x_{10})
,f_{2_1}(x'_1)\ldots f_{1_5}(\hat{x}'_5)f_{1_7}(x'_7)f_{1_9}(x'_9)f_{1_{10}}(x'_{10})
)$

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question is quite hard to read, as have been all your recent questions about the coproduct. But at least you have a nice answer

Comment: @FShrike I think the notion of coproducts for monoids and free monoids presented in most category theory texts are royally confusing in the sense that the word reduction bit don't give concrete examples.  Also, it doesn't shown whether the two notion of coproducts are the same or different, and if different, how?  Both involves word reduction of their strings.

Comment: @FShrike also, how is school and life.  Hey can we keep in touch outside of stackexchange via email?

Comment: @FShrike if you have a free moment, can I ask you if you can make sense of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731690/how-to-fill-out-the-last-row-for-the-included-sequential-machine-table).  I read over the section a billion times, and I still can't make heads and tails over the confusing notations.  Thanks.

Comment: respectfully, I'd rather not exchange email addresses here. However... feel free to join "the symplectic fortress" or "the affinoid union" which are discord servers frequented by many mse users including myself.

Comment: @FShrike what are those?  How much do they charge for joining?

Comment: no charge ${}{}$

Comment: @FShrike can you tell me the links to go to join.  I have never been on a discord server.  I actually, don't even know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by fixing some notation: I'll call $X \sqcup Y$ the disjoint union of *sets* (which is an instance of a categorical coproduct, in the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets and functions). I'll use $A + B$ for coproducts in a general category, e.g. the category $\mathbf{Mon}$ of monoids or the category $\mathbf{Grp}$ of groups. So, it'd make perfect sense to write something like

> In the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets, the coproduct is given by the disjoint union: $X + Y := X \sqcup Y$.

## Definition of coproducts of monoids

Now, assume you're given two monoids $\mathbf{A} = (A, \cdot, u)$ and $\mathbf{B} = (B, \times, e)$. We call $A$ the carrier of $\mathbf{A}$ (and similarly for $B$ and $\mathbf{B}$). Before going through the construction of their coproduct $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$, it might be instructive to see why its carrier cannot be $A \sqcup B$.

### What goes wrong with plain disjoint unions?

For this to be the case, we'd need to define two things:

- An operation $\bullet : (A \sqcup B) \times (A \sqcup B) \to (A \sqcup B)$
- An element $1 \in A \sqcup B$

Let's start looking at the latter. What should we choose? There are two natural candidates: $(u, 1)$ the identity from $\mathbf{A}$ and $(e, 2)$ the identity from $\mathbf{B}$. Let's put a pin on this problem: we'll get back to it in a second.

We'd also need to define $x \bullet y$ for any two elements $x, y \in A \sqcup B$. What should it be? There are four possible cases:

1. $x = (x_1, 1)$ and $y = (y_1, 1)$;
2. $x = (x_2, 2)$ and $y = (y_2, 2)$;
3. $x = (x_1, 1)$ and $y = (y_2, 2)$;
4. $x = (x_2, 2)$ and $y = (y_1, 1)$.

It's clear what $x \bullet y$ should be in the first two cases: $(x_1 \cdot y_1, 1)$ and $(x_2 \times y_2, 2)$ respectively. It's also immediate to see that case 1 requires the identity element to be $(u, 1)$, while case 2 requires the identity to be $(e, 2)$. But the identity cannot be both at the same time!

Another problem arises for cases 3 and 4: what should we pick? Remember, we don't just want to chose *any* value $x \bullet y$ that makes $A \sqcup B$ a monoid: we're trying to define a *coproduct*, and coproducts satisfy a universal property! Intuitively, we'd want to make the *most general* definition, and there doesn't seem to be a reasonable choice.

What we'd want to do is to *expand* the set $A \sqcup B$, so that $x \bullet y$ is a *new* element whenever we're in case 3 or 4, but have it be what we described above in cases 1 and 2. And since we're at it, we'd want $(u, 1)$ and $(e, 2)$ to be the same element, which will then be the identity element.

### The correct construction

We do this by following the recipe you describe: take $(A \sqcup B)^*$ to be the set of words whose letters are either elements of $A$ or of $B$, and then take $C \subset (A \sqcup B)^*$ to be the set of *reduced* such words. The claim is that we can define $\bullet$ and $1$, so that $(C, \bullet, 1)$ is a monoid, and moreover it satisfies the universal property of coproducts: $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} = (C, \bullet, 1)$.

The first thing to notice is that now, niehter $[(u, 1)]$ nor $[(e, 2)]$ are reduced; the reduction of both is the empty word $[]$. So it would make sense to define $1 := []$, which is exactly what we do.

Then, we can also notice that $(A \sqcup B)^*$ is already a monoid, but it doesn't take into account the monoid structures of $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{B}$: we just take concatenation of words. Not only that: $1$ is the identity with respect to such an operation!

So we might guess that to define $x \bullet y$ for $x, y \in C$, we first want to concatenate them (obtaining an element $x y \in (A \sqcup B)^*$ which might fail to be reduced) and then reduce it to an element of $C$.

## A concrete example

Here I'll drop the indices, since it will (hopefully!) be clear where each element comes from.

Before proving this is indeed a coproduct, let's look at a concrete example: let's pick $\mathbf{A} := (\mathbb{Z}, +, 0)$ the integers under addition, and $\mathbf{B} := (\{a, b\}^*, \cdot, \epsilon)$ the set of words on two letters, under concatenation (writing $\epsilon$ for the empty word). How do the reduction rules and operation on $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$ work?

Let's look an element which is not reduced: $x = [ab, 12, \epsilon, -7, ba]$. What is the corresponding element in $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$? First we remove the empty word, since it is the identity in $\mathbf{B}$, obtaining $x\prime = [ab, 12, -7, ba]$; then we notice that two adjacent elements both come from $\mathbf{A}$, so we perform the operation on them obtaining $x^{\prime \prime} = [ab, 5, ba]$. We can now see that what we got is reduced: it is indeed an element of $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$.

Now, let's look at $\bullet$. Fix two *reduced* elements, say $x = [ab, 5]$ and $y = [-5, ba, -2]$. To compute $x \bullet y$ we first concatenate them obtaining $xy = [ab, 5, -5, ba, -2]$ and then reduce it to $x \bullet y = [abba, -2]$ (by first adding 5 and -5 and obtaining 0, then removing it, then concatenating $ab$ and $ba$ obtaining $abba$).

## This is indeed a coproduct!

Let's fix monoids $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}$. To show that our construction is indeed a coproduct, what we need to show is that for any monoid $\mathbf{C}$, giving monoid homomorphisms $f : \mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{C}$, $g : \mathbf{B} \to \mathbf{C}$ is the same thing as giving a monoid homomorphism $h : \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \to \mathbf{C}$. Let's do this:

- $f, g$ determine $h$: given an element $x = [x_1, \dots, x_n]$ which is not necessarily reduced, we can define $h(x)$ as follows. First, since $h$ is to be a monoid homomorphism, we'd want $h(x) = h([x_1]) \cdot \dots \cdot h([x_n])$, so we only need to define $h(x_i)$. But we know that either $x_i = (a_i, 1)$ or $x_i = (b_i, 2)$: we can then define $h(x_i)$ to be $f(a_i)$ if we're in the former case, and $g(b_i)$ in the latter.

Notice that at this point, we still don't know that $h$ is a monoid homomorphism (and we haven't used the fact that $f, g$ are monoid homomorphisms). Formally we'd need to work with the reduction rules, but here I'll just sketch the relevant argument (and you can assemble it into a rigorous proof). Consider $x = [(x^\prime, 1)]$ and $y = [(y^\prime, 1)]$: is it the case that $h(x) \cdot h(y) = h(x \bullet y)$? Well, we can unwind our definition. $h(x) \cdot h(y) = f(x^\prime) \cdot f(y^\prime) = f(x^\prime \cdot y^\prime) = h([(x^\prime \cdot y^\prime, 1)]) = h(x \bullet y)$ (assuming $x^\prime \cdot y^\prime$ is not the identity, of course; what happens in that case?). The same applies for $g$.

- $h$ determines $f, g$: for this we can just define inclusions $in_1 : \mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$ by setting $in_1(a) = [(a, 1)]$ if $a$ is not the identity, and $[]$ if it is. The fact this is a monoid homomorphism follows from the reduction rules (we can just compute $in_1(a_1) \bullet in_1(a_2) = [(a_1, 1)] \bullet [(a_2, 1)] = [(a_1 \cdot a_2, 1)] = in_1(a_1 \cdot a_2)$), and we can define $f = h \circ in_1$. A similar argument involving $in_2(b) := [(b, 2)]$  applies for $g$.

## Questions

We're now ready to answer your questions.

1. The answer to this one is *no*. That is, if $a_1, \dots, a_n \in A$ this doesn't mean $[a_1, \dots, a_n] \in A$. Their *product* is, but the sequence isn't! On the other hand, the last part of your question is correct: the reduction of $[a_1, \dots, a_n, b_1, \dots, b_m]$ is an element of carrier of $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$.
2. The way you apply the reduction rules seems ok to me.
3. I don't think there's a misprint, though the notation might be slightly confusing: a less confusing way to write it might be $in_i : X_i \to C$ sending $x \mapsto in_i(x) :=$ reduction of $[(x, i)]$. In other words, it takes *one* element $x \in X_i$ to the one-element, reduced sequence with just $x$ marked by the index of the monoid $X_i$ it comes from (unless $x$ is an identity, in which case it gets sent to the empty sequence). I'll stress one thing though: $X_i$'s elements are *not* sequences (as per my answer to question 1)!
4. I'm not really sure what you're doing there, but I'll have to stress the fact that $C$ is *not* $X_1 \sqcup X_2$: it's a subset of the free monoid *on* the disjoint union: $C \subseteq (X_1 \sqcup X_2)^*$.

## Some general remarks

You seem to confuse monoids with free monoids: elements of a monoid are *not* sequences in general, that's only the case if the monoid is free over some set (what you call the set of words over some alphabet).

In the case of free monoids, by the way, your intuition seems to be kind of correct: fix (disjoint) alphabets $A$ and $B$, the coproduct of the free monoids $A^* + B^*$ is the free monoid over the disjoint union $(A \sqcup B)^*$.

Another thing I'd like to remark is that in the mathematical literature, people will usually define the carrier of the coproduct of monoids in a slightly different way. Fix two monoids $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$; take the free monoid over the disjoint union of the carriers $(A \sqcup B)^*$ and then define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on it: two words are related iff they reduce to the same word. It's then relatively painless to show that this relation interacts nicely with the monoid structure (that is, it is a *congruence*), so we can take the *quotient monoid*, and then prove that it satisfies the universal property of coproducts.

What we're doing here is to fix a canonical representative for each equivalence class (the element which is already reduced) and presenting this quotient as a subset instead.

Comment: I haven’t read through all of this but +1 for the effort alone

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone my profuse apologies for my late reply.  I have a couple of questions I am hoping if you can clarify.  1)  the term "carrier", does it mean an object, or an object with an assigned operation, e.g. an Algebra?  2) With regards to the injection map $\text{in}_i:X_i\to C$ sending $x\mapsto \text{in}_i(x):=\text{ reduction of...}$, the elements $x$s are individual elements of a string, $(x_1,\ldots, x_n),$ and because the $\text{in}_i$ being a homomorphism, we have

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone  $\text{in}_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\text{in}_i(x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot\text{in}_i(x_n):=\text{ reduction of } [(x_1,1)\cdot[(x_2,2)]\cdot\ldots\cdot[(x_n,n)]$
3) for the multiplication rule $(a_1\ldots a_n)\cdot (b_1\ldots b_m)=(a_1\ldots a_n, b_1\ldots b_m),$ if we have sasy $(a_1\ldots a_n)\in X_1$ and $(b_1\ldots b_m)\in X_2,$ to form the coproduct of $X_1\sqcup X_2,$ could $(a_1\ldots a_n)\cdot (b_1\ldots b_m)\in X_1\sqcup X_2$ ever?  If you think I am not making sense, please feel free to do so.  You are correct I am a bit confused about the rules between

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone coproduct of monoids, and free monoids.  I am not sure where the multiplication rule $(a_1\ldots a_n)\cdot (b_1\ldots b_m)=(a_1\ldots a_n, b_1\ldots b_m)$ fits in, because it seems that the multiplication rule along with rules for word reduction applies to forming coproduct of monoids and also to free monoids, but I am not sure if the multiplication rule apply simply to monoids in terms of operations that has nothing to do with forming coproduct.

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone 4)  The last question is, how did you learn how to figure out how to form coproducts and various categorical concepts for various mathematical concepts.  This is never talked about in introduction to category theory texts, like how do you know if what you are doing is correct.

Comment: @Seth Sorry it took me a while to get back to you. 1) by "carrier" I just mean the underlying object, without any additional structure; not sure what you mean in 2): the elements $x$ which end up in $in_i(x)$ are elements of $X_i$ which is _not_ a free monoid (at least in general), so no strings here. I'm similarly confused as to 3): elements of $X_i$ are not strings (again, unless it is a free monoid).

Comment: Moreover, for what you're asking to make sense, you either need $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ or the other way around (and even then, it's not straightforward to make sense of it). Finally, 4) is a very broad question: what do you mean by it?

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone do you mind if I email you and keep in touch and ask you about category theory. I found your website and I am not sure if you are open to such a request.  I want to ask you category theory related i stuff that is not this post related or else, the mods will bring the hammer down and kick us to chat.  I can email you with a subject heading that has stackexchange post on it.  I don't know a lot of people who works in category theory or related areas.  I do know that it is getting to be important and popular for applied reasons.

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone also for my third and fourth questions, basically, in the book's definition, it have few rules for working with strings for monoids:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\cdot(b_1,\ldots,b_m)=$$\text{reduction of }(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m).$

$\text{in}_i:X_i\to C$ $\quad x_i\mapsto\text{reduction of }(x_i,i)$...

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone I am not sure if I need to reduce strings twice.  Also, if $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in X_1$ and $ (b_1,\ldots,b_m)\in X_2$, then could $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\cdot(b_1,\ldots,b_m)\in X_1+X_2,$ Because f $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\cdot (b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ is a concatenation, and later on in $\textbf{(3)}$, it defines $a_j=(x_j,i_j),$ So...

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone $\text{in}_i((a_1,\ldots,a_n)\cdot(b_1,\ldots,b_m))=\text{in}_1((a_1,\ldots,a_n))\cdot \text{in}_2((b_1,\ldots,b_m))=\text{reduction of }(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m)=\text{reduction of }([(x_j,1_j)]\cdot [(x_j,1_j)]\cdot \ldots \cdot [(x_j,2_j)]\cdot\ldots \cdot [(x_j,2_j)]).$  I just don't know for the result of concatenation, can it ever be an element of the coproduct.

Comment: Regarding emails, I'd rather not (with all due respect). But I'd be happy to answer further questions you might have here on stackexchange. Regarding question 3, it doesn't really make sense to me: it seems you're still thinking about free monoids. Lastly, for question 4, I guess the only meaningful answer I can give is: as long as what you want has a universal property, you need to check if the construction respects it.

Comment: @LorenzoPerticone Sorry I just saw your reply today.  For some reasons, I must have missed the list of notifications from MSE.  Thank you for giving clarifications to all of my questions..