# Difference between coproduct of monoids and coproduct/product of free monoids.

Tags: category-theory, monoid

I posted about [monoid coproduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733556/correct-construction-of-coproduct-in-category-of-monoid-and-possible-misprint) to try to understand the correct way for constructing them.  In the process and from the answer I got, I am further confused whether the product and coproduct of plain monoids compare free monoids, what are the subtle differences in terms of what they look like.  I understand in both coproduct of monoids and free monoids, the process of word reduction to strings are applied.  I don't know anything beyond that.  I am hoping someone can explain to me their subtle differences.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If two monoids $M,N$ are free, say on sets $A$ and $B$, their coproduct $M*N$ is free as well, on the generating set $A+B$. You can prove this by hand, meaning you can prove that in $FA*FB$ there is no nontrivial relation between the elements, and that $A+B$ generates the monoid.

Or you can prove the universal property: functoriality of the free monoid construction gives monoid homomorphisms $FA\to F(A+B)\leftarrow FB$ induced by the inclusions $A\to A+B\leftarrow B$, whence a unique map $FA*FB\to F(A+B)$ by the universal property of coproducts. Now, this is a monoid isomorphism. (Alternatively: $FA\to F(A+B)\leftarrow FB$ is a coproduct cocone, which will imply $F(A+B)\cong FA*FB$ by uniqueness up to iso of a coproduct object.)

Or you can resort to slighty more abstract reasoning: $F : Set \to Mon$ is a left adjoint, hence it preserves colimits, hence coproducts: $F(A+B)\cong FA *  FB$.

Comment: basically to form coproducts of monoid, if the underlying monoids are free monoids, so will be their coproduct, otherwise, it will just be ordinary monoid coproduct?

Comment: another thing I want to ask, for both monoid coproduct and its free monoid cousins, do both coproducts look the same?

Comment: first question, yes. Second question, what do you mean?

Comment: if I have a pair of free monoids, and another pair of monoids, I form coproduct for both, do both coproduct look the same?  I think in my other post, when I tried to construct the coproduct of monoids, the person who answered the post said that I might be confused with free monoids.  I know that when forming coproducts for both, the processs of word reduction and deletion applies.  I also assumed that concatenation is allowed for both.   I am not sure when construction monoid or free monoid coproduct, whether word réductions and concatenation are both allowed.  Also....

Comment: do you have a reference where there are concrete examples presented that discusses more about the various categorical constructions of monoid, free monoids and abelian monoids.  I am always surprised at how people on here can just answer questions about how to do various categorical constructions for different math objects.  in category texts, it never talks about how one goes about checking if you have done the correct construction.

Comment: That's for a variety of reasons that appear more evident when you learn more category theory. In particular, in a very specific sense, when you know what to do in the category of Sets you know what to do everywhere (but the answer is not the same as the one in Set, and this is what baffles novices). As for a reference, an explicit construction of the coproduct of monoids is in Awodey's book on CT, as far as I remember.

Comment: but the coproduct for ordinary monoids and abelian monoids are different?  By the way, if two coproduct constructions look the same for two slightly different math objects, like abelian monoids and vector spaces, or different, is it easy to prove they are the same or different?  In my second question, i was really asking if the construction of coproduct for monoids is the same as for construction for free monoids.  I think there is the issue of concatenation for free monoids, but not for monoids.  i am not sure at this point.

Comment: "but the coproduct for ordinary monoids and abelian monoids are different?" they are different, yes. Given two commutative monoids, their coproduct in $Mon$, $M*N$, is not commutative, while their coproduct in $CMon$, $M\oplus N$, is.

Comment: "if two coproduct constructions look the same for two slightly different math objects, like abelian monoids and vector spaces, or different, is it easy to prove they are the same or different?" It is impossible to answe this question precisely, because the question itself is very imprecise. There is a somewhat deep reason why coproduct of (say) abelian groups and of vector spaces look so similar.

Comment: when you say "given two commutative monoids, their coproduct in $,$ $∗,$ is not commutative, while their coproduct in $\textit{},$ $\oplus ,$ is"  Is there a classic concrete example of this?  Also, the notion of string concatenation only applies to the case of free monoid, especially in the case of forming their coproduct. But for plain monoid, when forming coproduct, only the two rules for word reduction applying to strings: (Multiply adjacent pairs with the same $−$term, and deleting of identity terms) .

Comment: Can I ask how did you yourself learn to construct various categorical concepts for various mathematical objects and develop the confidence or methods to know that what you are doing checks out mathematically?

Comment: More than constant exercise for me, it has been useful to see another mathematician in front of me doing the thing. The confidence never developed, more of an habit to recognize what is "evidently true".

Comment: I am learning category theory on my own by going through a textbook with exercises.  I find there are a lot of things that are not really explained well.

Comment: is there a concrete example where an abelian monoid when form as an ordinary coproduct is not abelian, but when formed as a vector space coproduct, it is abelian?

Comment: The coproduct of $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z,+)$ with itself, considered as a monoid, is not abelian, because in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, where the first copy is presented as $langle a\mid a^3\rangle$ and the second copy as $langle b\mid b^3\rangle$, the element $ab$ is not equal to the element $ba$.

Comment: On the other hand, the coproduct of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ with itself *as a vector space over $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$* [ha]s [an] abelian [underlying monoid].

Comment: thank you so very much for the example and for answering all my questions.  I really appreciate it.